# How to update/insert cell in variables using Python in SPSS

Tags: python, spss

I'm using this code to read a set of cases from dataset:

```
begin program.
with spss.DataStep():
start = 0
end = 3
firstColumn = 'deviation'
datasetObj = spss.Dataset('DataSet1')
variables = datasetObj.varlist
caseData = datasetObj.cases

print([itm[0] for itm in caseData[start:end, variables[firstColumn].index]])

spss.EndDataStep()
end program.
```

Now, I want to change [this cell](http://screencast.com/t/6lanvfxZldU) based on the variable name and case number.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190699/print-result-to-cell-spss-python-script) and answer related to my issue, but I can't use `spss.Submit` inside `with spss.DataStep():`

Comment: Not sure if I follow. In particular what the code above relates to with the data in screenshot provided. Further more the logical criteria for changing that one cell? Some further clarity is needed.

Comment: @JigneshSutar My apologies, I didn't clear that enough in the code, I've changed it now. The code above just will view the list from case 0 to 3 like this `[0.99,1.1,0.93,0.97]` and print them. I just want to change one cell/item value from variable which called `deviation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See **Example: Modifying Case Values** from [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.python.help/python_package_dataset.htm) page.

```
*python_dataset_modify_cases.sps.
DATA LIST FREE /cust (F2) amt (F5).
BEGIN DATA
210 4500
242 6900
370 32500
END DATA.
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spss
spss.StartDataStep()
datasetObj = spss.Dataset()
for i in range(len(datasetObj.cases)):
   # Multiply the value of amt by 1.05 for each case
   datasetObj.cases[i,1] = 1.05*datasetObj.cases[i,1][0]
spss.EndDataStep()
END PROGRAM.
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was easy like that, moreover I tried but like this `datasetObj.cases[1][1]` :)